# Unresolved reference to symbol in Wix

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, wix, wix-extension

I am trying to create a installer for MVC4 application using Wix. I found an example that shows how to create an installer for a MVC4 Application at [this link](https://github.com/BartDM/WIXInstallerDemo)

**But when I try to build the Wix Setup Project, it gives me errors like below**

```
Error   16  Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:MyWebWebComponents' 
in section 'Product:{D16E42B5-3C6F-4EE5-B2F4-727BF8B74A92}'.    
C:\Users\Baris\Desktop\New folder\WIXInstallerDemo-master\DemoWebsite.Setup\Product.wxs 15  
1   DemoWebsite.Setup

Error   17  Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:DemoWebsiteIssConfiguration' 
in section 'Product:{D16E42B5-3C6F-4EE5-B2F4-727BF8B74A92}'.    
C:\Users\Baris\Desktop\New folder\WIXInstallerDemo-master\DemoWebsite.Setup\Product.wxs 16  
1   DemoWebsite.Setup`
```

**I tried adding WixUIExtension as a reference but it doesn't work.**

**This is the Product.wxs. And feature node's children nodes causes this error**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="{D16E42B5-3C6F-4EE5-B2F4-727BF8B74A92}" Name="Demo website setup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Me" UpgradeCode="9279b740-8419-45c4-9538-6a45f8e949c7">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="DemoWebsite.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Property Id="DB_USER" Value="sa"/>
    <Property Id="DB_PASSWORD" Value="sa"/>
    <Property Id="DB_SERVER" Value="LOCAL"/>
    <Property Id="DB_DATABASE" Value="DemoWebsite"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="DemoWebsite.Setup" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyWebWebComponents" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="DemoWebsiteIssConfiguration" />
    </Feature>
    <!-- Specify UI -->
    <UIRef Id="MyUI" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INETPUB" />
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <!-- Will default to C:\ if that is the main disk-->
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <!-- Will reference to C:\inetpub-->
      <Directory Id="INETPUB" Name="Inetpub">
        <!-- Will reference to c:\Inetpub\Demowebsite-->
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="DemoWebsite">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

What am I doing wrong? I know its very specific for SO but I cannot find any solution on the web.

I am using VS 2012- Wix 4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message says it all: it expects a `ComponentGroup`-tag containing your components (containing e.g. files or registry keys). If you take a look at the example project that you linked in your question, the `<ComponentGroupRef Id="DemoWebsiteIssConfiguration" />`-element references a `ComponentGroup` with the name `DemoWebsiteIssConfiguration`. You can find this in the file `DemoWebsite.Setup\IISConfiguration.wxs`:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="DemoWebsiteIssConfiguration">
  <ComponentRef Id="InstallWebsite" />
  <ComponentRef Id="DemoWebsiteAppPool" />
</ComponentGroup>
```

It is a `ComponentGroup` which contains two components or, in this case, references to two components. These components are defined above the `ComponentGroup`-element in the same file.

Regarding the other `ComponentGroupRef` with the id `MyWebComponents`: The referenced `ComponentGroup` is created dynamically during the build. You can take a look at the file `DemoWebsite.Setup\setup.build`. This file is a [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/wea2sca5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)-file used to build the setup. It contains a target named `Harvest` that invokes `heat`, another tool in the WiX Toolset package. `heat` will parse e.g. a directory and gather all the files contained within and put them in a `ComponentGroup` that you can reference in your source file. I.e. you define a reference to a `ComponentGroup` and then you can create the *content* of this dynamically. This way you don't have to bother if a file is added to or removed from the project, as `heat` will gather them dynamically.

```
 <Target Name="Harvest">
    <!-- Harvest all content of published result -->
    <Exec
        Command='$(WixPath)heat dir $(Publish) -dr INSTALLFOLDER -ke -srd -cg MyWebWebComponents -var var.publishDir -gg -out $(WebSiteContentCode)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />
  </Target>
```

The name of the dynamically created `ComponentGroup` is defined with the parameter `-cg`. you can invoke `heat` with the parameter `-?` for a short description of the possible parameters.

Comment: +1 informative answer. I found the IISConfiguration.wxs and put it to the Wix project then one problem is gone. And only one is left and related with <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyWebWebComponents" />. Where should I get the MyWebWebComponents ? The setup.build already in there doesnt help the wix project to be build. Should I manually generate it by using heat ? (Note: I am using Wix 4.0 now)

Comment: Downloading the whole project, creating a `publish`-folder in `DemoWebsite.Setup`, putting some files in it and then invoking `msbuild setup.build` will build an MSI, harvesting all the files in the created `DemoWebsite.Setup\publish`-folder. However you could also create a source file with the related `ComponentGroup` manually by yourself or use `heat` to harvest a directory with the needed files. `heat` will create another WiX source file that you have to reference on invoking `candle` and `light`, so the referenced `ComponentGroup` is found. Use the `Exec`-taks in `setup.build` as examples.